# How do I add starter content to a project manually?

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unreal-engine4

I think I'm experiencing a bug where if I delete a project, then create a project with the same name indicating I want it to have starter content, it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 3):

I've been getting this bug as well recently (with v4.14.0)

If anyone else has this issue, you need to find the `Content Browser`. Click the `Add New` button then chose `Add Feature or Content Pack` from the menu. On the `Content Packs` tab and you should see some options there for either the normal starter content or the mobile version.

Note that once you've done this you should be able to find the starter map (with the chairs) in:
`Content > StarterContent > Maps > Minimal_Default`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to add starter content to an established project via the launcher. You can, however, just create a new project with the starter content and then move it to your old project. To do this you have to right-click on the starter content in your content browser and use the **migrate** option.